# AngularJS ng-options with several fields

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a collection of objects with user info.

```
"Id": "1",
"Firstname": "ABCDEF",
"Lastname": "GHIJK",
"Middlename": ""
```

In my select options I want to display two fields - `Firstname Lastname`. I don't get how to do it and how to bind it to `ng-model`.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can try this :

```
<select 
  name="users" 
  ng-model="selectedUser" 
  ng-options="user.Id as user.Firstname + ' ' + user.Lastname for user in users">
</select>
```

More information in the documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: can we add multiple values also if selectedUser is object in model, like i want `selectedUser.Firstname as user.firstname and selectedUser.Lastname as user.lastname can we do that in ng-options?

Comment: I recommend creating a filter.  Use it like this ng-options="user.Id as (user | userFullName) for user in users"

Answer (score 14):

Considering the format of your array object to be like this.

```
$scope.userInfo = [
                    {"Id": "1", "Firstname": "ACDEF", "Lastname": "GHIJK", "Middlename": ""},
                    {"Id": "2", "Firstname": "BADEF", "Lastname": "HIGJK", "Middlename": ""},
                    {"Id": "3", "Firstname": "CDBEF", "Lastname": "IIHJK", "Middlename": ""},
                ]
```

You can display two fields like this and and bind it to the model as shown below.

```
<select ng-model="userInfo" ng-options="s.Firstname +' '+ s.Lastname for s in userInfo" class="span2"> </select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just an additional update,

I had to show the Last name enclosed in brackets so here is how I modified the answer and got it working.

```
<select 
   name="users" 
   ng-model="selectedUser" 
   ng-options="user.Id as user.Firstname + ' (' + user.Lastname + ') ' for user in users">
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Theres is always in a non `ng-options` scenario, where you can bind two params from the `ng-repeat` item:

```
  <select name="user" ng-model="vm.asignedUser">
    <option value="">Select user</option> 
    <option value="{{ {'name':user.name, 'id': user.id} }}" ng-repeat="user in vm.users">
      {{ user.nombreLargo }}
    </option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`<select ng-model="color" ng-options="(c.name+' '+c.shade) for c in colors"></select>`

Source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/ljJd5x1Tgrk/bZuVWCA1hO4J